# how to remove .php extension from url on server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove `extension(.php)` from URL and for these I have use this code in htaccess file:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

and its properly working on the local server and also on one of my live websites.

But it's not working on this [site](https://www.guaranteeoption.com/).

Comment: Please ensure that any .htaccess is working at all. Because it seems that your webserver is not supporting htaccess right now (needs to set AllowOverride All in apache config or adequate option in other webserver you are using.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score -1):

## htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

## View page index.php

Add anchor tag in index.php page and add url in anchor tag for demo.php

```
echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."demo' >Demo </a>";
```

## View page demo.php

```
<h1>Welcome to Demo page</h1>
```